# C# dependency injection multiple implementation of the same Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, dependency-injection

**Note :  this is not a duplicate !**

I have the following **Example** :

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
...

}

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
...

}

public class Repository<SpecialClass> : IRepository<SpecialClass> 
{

...
}


public class SpecialClass: IEntity
{
...
}
```

Now I want to use `Repository<>` class for every `IRepository<>` except for `IRepository<SpecialClass>` :

```
// every IRepository<> :
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(RepositoryEFCore<>));

// but not for SpecialClass
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<SpecialClass>), typeof(Repository<SpecialClass>));
```

The question is how do I register two(or multiple) different classes for the same interface while the interface has already been registered for another class ?

Comment: switch the order of registration and see if that works. Register the special case first. I am also assuming this is using the default built-in container.

Comment: @Nkosi, I doubt switching order will matter. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I don't seem to get your question. Your code seems to me you've already done what you want. If you are using the default DI, the order matters like @Nkosi said. If you register generic first, then register specific, when you resolve `IRepository<SpecialClass>` the DI injects the last added service, in your case the `Repository<SpecialClass>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(RepositoryEFCore<>));
```

This line will add all IRepository handler in DI container. To exclude some special class from DI registration, there is a way using reflection,

```
 Type[] handlers = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Name != "SpecialClass" &&  t.GetInterfaces().
        Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRepository<>))).ToArray();

        foreach (Type concreteHandler in handlers)
        {
            Type? handlerInterface = concreteHandler.GetInterfaces().First(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRepository<>));
            services.AddScoped(handlerInterface, concreteHandler);
        }
```

Here, handlers array will hold all concrete implementation  of IRepository excluding **Specialclass** and using foreach you can add all objects with concrete implementation in DI.